# Microsoft Account password change on Skype retains the old password on Windows 10 login, how come?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, login, skype, microsoft-account

I have been facing the following strange behaviour on Microsoft Account password
(there is also other closely same case posts in here):

- the Microsoft Account is based on a Gmail Account, with a different password
- the password was changed on Skype, and now well working for it and also for Microsoft Account general login
- the old password is despite now still valid for Windows 10 Microsoft Account login

Seems quite strange, and even frightening, if there may arise some contradiction or mess with/between those two different passwords for this critical Microsoft Account ...

What to do now, or maybe what not to do, anyway to be safe in future?

Comment: Disconnect the account from your profile, the connect it, this is well know behavior since Windows 8 was released.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, thanks for your reply, seems very applicable, will check this with my pal's Laptop soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, changed the Microsoft password once again, and got the case cleared. Anyway thanks for @Ramhound for the hint.